# How to have a formatter both for eslint and std javascript/typescript on VsCode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am using **vscode** and in many projects I'm using **eslint** with Typescript/Javascript.

If I set eslint as the formatter for those languages, **the default Typescript/Javascript formatters are no more used if a project is without eslint**.

How can I specify to vscode "Use the EslintFormatter if the project is using eslint, otherwise use the std Javascript/Typescript one".

Note: I don't want to have a per-project configuration, I'd prefer to have a dynamic decision if possible

Comment: set the formatter to `EslintFormatter` in the workspace settings for workspaces that have eslint

Answer (score 0):

A repository should take care of linting with the right settings. There are a lot of standards (tools) that stack on each other.

This answer aims to be inclusive with editors and IDEs including, but not limited to: VSC, IntelliJ, vim

There are in fact two topics hidden in your question

1. Style (tabs, indents, braces, semi-columns)
2. Avoiding errors, build-time or runtime

The most basic *style* tools are:

1. [editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/) > include a .editorconfig in your repo
2. [prettier](https://prettier.io/) > aimed just for styling
3. in your case, specific VSC settings in .vscode/settings.json. You can include collapse on indent, some VSC specific things, like recommended plugins (work only in vscode). https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Then there is the part of avoiding errors. This can be done using eslint. You should add your eslint file in your repo and use eslint to lint it before commiting.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html. Prettier can run as a plugin for eslint.

If you can configure eslint as your default formatter: https://education.launchcode.org/gis-devops/configurations/06-vscode-eslint/index.html

- prettier is able to fix style things in bulk `npx prettier . --write` https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html
- also eslint is able to fix things in bulk `npx eslint --fix` https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface
- you can even go the extra mile by adding a pre-commit hook in git: https://prettier.io/docs/en/precommit.html

However you should work with your team to decide on a standard. A good starting point could be adopting an existing style guide and tweak that. Most popular are: Idiomatic, JavaScript Standard Style, Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide, Google JavaScript Style Guide.

Mind changing styles can result in green-wall commits and angry co-developers.